# Is it possible to show unicode characters in a HTML input type=submit value?

Tags: jquery, html, unicode

A customer has a designer mockup of a form button that shows a right facing triangle character after the main text, but I can't seem to get this showing. The offending markup is;

```html
    <input type="submit" value="Add to basket &#9654;" />
```

This should look like 'Add to basket ▶' (if it renders in your browser).

Is this possible or am I doing something wrong?

A jquery workaround is acceptable as a hack too. The page is HTML5 compliant, maybe that'll help.

Thanks in advance,

Ryan

**Update:** The answers below are correct, there was an easier way though, I just copied the triangle out of this question and straight into me HTML editor. No encoding needed.

Thanks all.

Comment: All of the web pages that I have seen that do this use an image as a fake submit button.

Comment: Works for me (chrome). Is there a limit on the width of the button?

Comment: Works in Win2k3+IE8/Chrome/FF, doesn't work in XP/SP3+IE8/IE7.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ya you can use 100%

just ensure

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

should be present.

The meta tag is ignored by browsers if the HTTP header is present.

Also ensure that your file is actually encoded as UTF-8 before serving it, check/try the following:

Ensure your editor save it as UTF-8.

Ensure your FTP or any file transfer program does not mess with the file.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

`<button type='submit'>Add to basket &#9654;</button>`

It has the same effect as `<input type='button'>`, but you can also write charset inside.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

[Yes it is possible.](http://jsbin.com/owuku3)

Make sure to use utf-8 meta:

```
<meta charset=utf-8 />
```

Answer (score 0):

See the late Alan Flavell's page [FORM submission and i18n](http://niwo.mnsys.org/saved/~flavell/charset/form-i18n.html) about the issue. It's years old but, as far as I know, still relevant.

In short: form submission happens in the same encoding as the html page itself is in. So you have to provide a usable encoding for the html page.